# Cycle plugin refuses to scroll, no idea why

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, gallery, cycle

I"m trying to make a gallery piece for my website. I know there are ones out there that would do most of what I want automatically but I'm hoping to be able to build my own that way I know exactly what's gone into it.

Problem is, it's not working. Sort of.

The CSS works as it's supposed to. The jQuery Cycle plugin is providing the sexy bits but it only works if I set the animation to Fade. If I tell it to scrollLeft or scrollHorz it fails. Why?

I know I'm using the latest jQuery Cycle plugin (with all the animations) and I'm properly linking to jQuery and I am linking to the Easing plugin for good measure. No go. No errors, either.

Any ideas?

You can see my code here: http://www.designbyadmiral.com/tests/gallery/index.html

Comment: You should use the Firebug plugin with Firefox. It'll tell you what (if any) JavaScript errors you have, and any console debugging output other developers may have added. For example, it originally said you had an error with the `$slideswidth` line. Now it says "`[cycle] unknown transition: scrollHorz ; slideshow terminating`."

Comment: @Jimyi I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `jquery.cycle-2.71.js` on your site:

```
// transition definitions - only fade is defined here, transition pack defines the rest
$.fn.cycle.transitions = {
```

You ned the "transition pack" or the "with all transitions" version of the plugin.

Comment: That's very annoying, I thought I had it. Right, well it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: also, if you have `left: !important` on the slide, scrollHorz won't work.